# Pasar un problema de Excel Solver a Python, que libreria me recomendarías ? Y si sabes como resolverlo, te agradecería

Tags: python, optimización

[image: Esquema a solucionar]

En la imagen adjunto el problema que tengo que resolver, se trata de optimizar la distribución de unos promedios en dos grupos diferentes donde la diferencia de la sumatoria de los promedios de cada grupo sea mínima.

```
       def solver(promedios):
    teamsize=len(promedios)/2
    n=len(promedios)

    m = GEKKO(remote=True)

    #SCORES


    #initialize variables
    x = [m.Var(value=1, lb=0, ub=1) for i in range(n)]
    y = [m.Var(value=1, lb=0, ub=1) for i in range(n)]

    #Equations
    for i in range(n):
        m.Equation(x[i]+y[i]==1)

    #Objective
    m.Minimize(([m.sum(promedios[i]*x[i] for i in range(n)]+[m.sum(promedios[i]*y[i] for i in range(n)])**2)

    #Set global options
    #m.options.IMODE = 3 #steady state optimization
    m.options.SOLVER = 5

    #Solve simulation
    m.solve(disp=False) # solve on public server

        # show final objective
solver([1.5, 1.5, 2, 1])
```

> Por ejemplo: para la entrada del código [1.5, 1.5, 2, 1]. El equipo
> uno que sería el vector X debería dar: [1, 1, 0, 0] El equipo dos que
> sería el vector Y debería dar: [0, 0, 1, 1]
>
> Cada valor promedio, es un jugador (y el valor un promedio de los
> partidos ganados). Por eso x[0]+y[0], debería ser 1 por que es el
> mismo jugador y no debería estar en ambos equipos.

Comment: Google "python resolver optimización excel"

Comment: Hola, ahí adjunte lo que hice yo. Esta tarea no me la dio nadie, se me ocurrio para ayudar a distribuir los equipos en un torneo de futbol para que se armen equipos parejos en base a los jugadores que asistan. No tengo profesor, y lo hago todo como autodidacta. Lo resolvi en Excel, pero en Python todavía no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

Comment: Ponle ejemplo de entrada y salida para chequear una solución.

Comment: Hola Candid Moe, ahí le agregue un ejemplo. Gracias por contestar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro de haberlo entendido bien, pero tengo está posible solución:

```
def reparte(promedios):
    prom = sorted([(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(promedios)], reverse=True)
    teamA = []
    teamB = []
    sumA = 0
    sumB = 0
    for x, i in prom:
        if sumA > sumB:
            teamB.append(i)
            sumB += x
        else:
            teamA.append(i)
            sumA += x
    return (teamA, sumA), (teamB, sumB)
```

Lo que hace es ordenar los promedios en orden descendentes y luego va asignado cada valor al equipo que acumule la menor sumatoria.

Me parece que el resultado minimiza la diferencia, aunque no he trabajo en una demostración.

#### Demo

Esta demo imprime cada equipo como las posiciones originales del promedio, en lugar de un vector como pide el OP. Ambas formas son equivalentes.

```
def reparte(promedios):
    prom = sorted([(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(promedios)], reverse=True)
    teamA = []
    teamB = []
    sumA = 0
    sumB = 0
    for x, i in prom:
        if sumA > sumB:
            teamB.append(i)
            sumB += x
        else:
            teamA.append(i)
            sumA += x
    return (teamA, sumA), (teamB, sumB)

promedios = [1.5, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14.2, 4.1, 23.3, 0.4443]
teamA, teamB = reparte(promedios)
print(teamA)
print(teamB)
```

produce:

```
([16, 11, 10, 8, 7, 1, 5, 4, 17], 47.244299999999996)
([14, 13, 12, 9, 15, 6, 2, 0, 3], 46.800000000000004)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Me gusto como lo resolviste, ahora lo testeo y ya te confirmo si cumple con la función. Muchisimas gracias, por tomarte el tiempo.

Comment: Hace exactamente lo que necesitaba. Muchisimas gracias. Muy buena la forma en que lo resolviste, ultimamente estoy usando mucho el solver de Excel y mi cabeza ni se le ocurre estas resoluciones más prácticas. Muy amable.
Y te consulto si quisiera hacer con optimización con gekko, tambien se podría ? Por que tengo otros proyectos que tal vez si los necesite, aunque tambien puede que sirva esta función que elaboraste.

Comment: No conozco Gekko.